# What is ThreeExtras.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm attempting to deconstruct [this webGL moon](http://whiteflashwhitehit.com/2011/02/21/a-moon-in-webgl/), which uses ThreeExtras.js.

Threeextras.js seems to be some variant of Three.js plus some pieces from elsewhere in the repo; is there any documentation for it, or description of how it differs from standard Three.js?

(I also found a repository of variant builds, but no docs or mention of origin besides the three.js repo.)
http://www.chandlerprall.com/threebuilds/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThreeExtras.js lived in the repository until r49. You can look at it at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r49. After that things moved around. You would have to look at the `migration guide` at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration and the `changes log` at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js to see how you can bring the code to the latest release or ask questions about specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking to deconstruct in the WebGL moon demo are the texture-based effects, here is some information: in more recent versions of Three.js, some of the texture effects such as bump mapping and specular mapping were incorporated into THREE.MeshPhongMaterial. For an example of a similar set of effects -- say, for the planet Earth -- check out the example at:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Earth.html

The particularly relevant code is:

```
// Create the Earth with nice texturing - normal map for elevation, specular highlights
var sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 64, 32);  

var colors = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/earth-day.jpg" );
var bumps  = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/earth-topo.jpg" );
var shine  = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/earth-specular.jpg" );

var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, map: colors, 
    bumpMap: bumps, bumpScale: 4, specular: 0xffffff, specularMap: shine, emissive: 0x888888 } );

var earthSphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeo, earthMaterial ); 
scene.add(earthSphere);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I saw that same WebGL moon demo and decided to see if I could do better. If you'd like to see how you can do something similar with the latest version of Three.JS you can check out my [**Moon Demo**](http://github.com/CoryG89/MoonDemo). There is a blog posted linked to on the repository page, but it's a work in progress. If you don't mind digging into the code though, you'll probably be able to use it better than the demo you're looking at now. Here is the [**live demo**](http://coryg89.github.io/MoonDemo) if you want to check it out. It implements the diffuse lighting and also the normal mapping. No specular lighting was applied however.